# How to receive mails for multiple accounts with google domains

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, gmail

I have this issue with my Google Domain mails in Outlook (2007 and 2010) and Outlook in Windows 8 Mobile when last week I tried to add the same account to Outlook in multiple Computer and Mobile Devices.The issue is that I receive all mails in my outlook 2010 but now I only receive some or partially mails in my Outlook 2007 and in my Mobile Outlook.
The account settings is exactly the same in both Outlook also I Leave a copy of messages on the server.
Any suggestions on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution i found from Google:

Using POP on multiple clients or mobile devices

What is 'recent mode?'

If you're accessing Gmail on multiple clients through POP, Gmail's 'recent mode' makes sure that all messages are made available to each client, rather than only to the first client to access new mail.

Recent mode fetches the last 30 days of mail, regardless of whether it's been sent to another POP client already.

Setting up 'recent mode'

In your POP client settings, replace 'username@gmail.com' in the 'Username' or 'Email' field with 'recent:username@gmail.com'

Once you enable recent mode, please be sure to configure your POP client to leave messages on the server according to the instructions below:

```
Outlook or Outlook Express: on the Advanced tab, check the box next to 'Leave a copy of messages on the server.'
Apple Mail: on the Advanced tab, remove the check next to 'Remove copy from server after retrieving a message.'
Thunderbird: on the Server Settings tab, check the box next to 'Leave messages on server.'
```